# How to get public wall posts

Tags: android, facebook-c#-sdk

How can I read user public posts/photos using his Facebook ID number?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A GET request to `https://graph.facebook.com/{user id}/feed?access_token={your access token}` will do it. Try it out in the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: What is my access token? how can I get it?

Comment: If you write your own app, follow the instructions in the authentication part of the documentation. If you're just looking to see how it works, the Graph API Explorer i linked to above will get you an access token for use in its interface